# How do I know the window of my view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

`ViewWillAppear` is never called automatically I have to call them manually. `ViewWillDisappear` is often called though.

I do not know where to debug this.

I suppose the problem is because I created the application on 4.1 where people have to call `viewWillAppear` explicitly.

I suppose, because `viewWillAppear` will be called depending on its relation with window I can check if my `viewController` has an outlet to window.

How do I do so?

I suspected the problem is somewhere in my delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"a08863b514ef09558ba82fec070cc7468fdbeeae"];
    if(getenv("NSZombieEnabled") || getenv("NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled"))
    {
        NSLog(@"NSZombieEnabled/NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled enabled!");
    }

    [self.window addSubview:self.navController.view]; //This seem to be the problem. I should have specified the viewController and not the view

    [self.navController pushViewController:self.MainBadgerApplication animated:YES];
    //[cachedProperties singleton].lastAnchor =[cachedProperties currentLocation];
    [cachedProperties singleton].currentAnchor=[cachedProperties currentLocation];
    self.MainBadgerApplication.selectedIndex=0;
    [BNUtilitiesQuick tabBarController:self.MainBadgerApplication didSelectViewController:self.MainBadgerApplication.selectedViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I suspected that
[self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];  is the issue.

Also I've heard before ios5 you do have to call viewController explicitly. So should I create a different program for ios5 and ios4 (not like there is any danger in calling viewController twice for my program)

Comment: For window you can check - self.view.window. But you won't need to call viewWillAppear explicitly, it calls automiatically in the lifecycle of view controller.

Comment: It doesn't call viewWillAppear explicitly. That is the problem.

Comment: one thing for which you need to be sure is that you never need to call any view controller life cycle.I suspect on navigation controller heirarchy, you can try logging NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers); and check what is the view controller heirarchy present there.

Comment: That's a start. Thanks a lot Rishi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspected that `[self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];` is the issue.

Probably. You should be doing this instead:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

Just adding the view doesn't put your view controller into the hierarchy properly. See the WWDC 2011 view controller containment video for more information.